# SQL SELECT rows where count are equal

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a query to select a bunch of rows by some values.
This is an example of my table:

```
*my_table*
number  item     status
01      hat      on delivery
01      gloves   delivered
01      sock     cancel
02      hat      cancelled
02      gloves   delivered
02      sock     cancelled
```

I´d like to do send all rows which are delivered or cancelled values to archive.
I tried something like this,

```
Select *
from my_table
where status = "cancelled" and status = "delivered"
```

but it didn´t work.

Comment: Which database program are you using?

Comment: Don't you mean: `where status = 'cancelled' or status = 'delivered'` ?

Answer (score 3):

As you said you should use or:

```
Select *
from my_table
where status = 'cancelled' or status = 'delivered'
```

Mostly because status can not have the two values at the same time.

Comment: Good answer. Upvoting you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use OR clause

```
Select *
from my_table
where (status = 'cancelled' or status = delivered);
```

Make sure you enclose in brackets if you use or condition when ever you have multiple WHERE clauses